# java-box-sdk - Search Plugin

Tags: java, box

With Box, there is a search interface, where you type in your query and it gives you the top matching documents according to their content. I would like to change it with my own search algorithm; however, I do not know how to do it. Ideally, would like it to be a plug-in. Do I have to create my own application? I just want to change the searching module of the web interface, so I feel like building my own app is an overkill.

Comment: I assume you are talking about https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk ?

Comment: The search interface i talk about is [this](https://app.box.com/folder/0). It is the web interface of Box, where you can manipulate your acoutn as you wish. In that interface, you can also do searches. I would like to add a plug-in such that it proposes an alternative way of searching within my folders.

The link you gave is to build a Java application. I feel like I would need to build my own app with this SDK, but I was hoping someone might show me another solution.